# Add plugins (Vue.use) after instance mounting (new Vue().$mount())

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, web, server

I have some vue plugins, like analytics, sentry etc. which require  configuration data from server to set up.

I have to make a request for configuration, next do a `Vue.use()` and in the end, call `new Vue() instance`. I think it can make some performance effort because `Vue.$mount` creates a lot of DOM elements and runs javascript logic and it happens after XHR request/response. So my question is: what is the best solution, patterns to solve described problem?

Can I avoid fetching configuration data (maybe put data in some static file by webpack during build process (data are stored in MySQL)
Or maybe can I use Vue.use after creating Vue instance?

Comment: Fetching the config doesn't require Vue instance. You can fetch it and then init. This is one of several ways to do this and not a bad one.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer avoid fetching configuration data in server. In my opition you must put the configuration in static file for building with webpack.

But I will answer your question: the Vue don't have restrictions about to load plugins after Vue instance created. It's work.

See the bellow example.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button type="button" @click="installPlugin">install plugin</button>
    <button type="button" @click="callPlugin">call plugin</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  methods: {
    installPlugin() {
      Vue.use({
        install(Vue, options) {
          console.log('plugin was installed');

          Vue.prototype.$test = () => {
            console.log('plugin was called');
            return 'run-test';
          };
        },
      });
    },
    callPlugin() {
      this.$test();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

In this example, the Vue Plugin can be installed and called after Vue instance created.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people.

Comment: excuse me, what plugin is being installed in your example? or, where and how can a plugin be installed in your example? Thanks

Comment: @dexter00x the plugin is the install() function. you can replace anything within the Vue.use( with the name of any plugin you imported.